# ios app + web app business model

Tags: android, ios, iphone, web-applications, paypal

Firstly, I am not a 100% sure that this is the right place to ask this question so please accept my apologies if its not and point me to the right place to post this question.

We are developing an app that we would like to commercialise and sell. The app will have a web-based version and native iOS and Android versions.

Now, my question is regarding the model that we can use for commercialisation and how to make it easy for the users. I have the following options and would like some feedback or experiences.

1. The first option is to have users register on our website and subscribe by payment. Then have them use the registered user credentials on the web to access web app and inside the iOS and Android versions to gain access to the contents. Ofcourse the users would be able to download the native apps free from the app stores and they will also have the option of registering through the mobile app and providing payment details through there. Now, is this considered as in-app purchase? Or is it free from Apple's point of view and they wouldn't charge us anything?

   2. Have users download paid version of the native apps. In that case they purchase the app straight away and make payment through app store or similar. But, in that case is it possible for us to find out their app store credentials or something that identifies them so that we can give them free web access.
   3. We could sell native paid apps on the store and charge users separately for the web based version that they can use on their laptops. This has the disadvantage that the user will have to make two separate purchases.

Your thoughts are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Apple states in it's terms and conditions for in app purchases that you cannot sell in-app content by other means than their iap system. Now if this considered in-app content? Depends on the content I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might look at the terms and conditions or, if you are too lazy ask the support politely what is considernd an in-app purchase and what not. I think this is not considerd an in app purchase, because you don't purchase a special item but a service. But then again, but then again: termas and conditions can be weird.
2. I don' think that your users will accept this, because, as you mentioned, they will have to pay twice for one service.

My recomendation is: contact apple and google support for terms and conditions regarding in-app purchases, because that's the best experience for the user and you will make the most money.